# bootstrap and ratchet at the same time?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web-applications, ratchet

I'm making a mobile web site with bootstrap.
I just found out there's a framework called `ratchet`.

With the bootstrap only approach, I was thinking something like the following:

> We build mobile web first, and modify a few pages in pc.

Now I know there's a framework for better mobile ui, I am wondering if I could plan like the following:

> 1. We build mobile web first using ratchet for header and navigation, and
>      bootstrap for other functionalities such as tabs, collapse, and other
>      bootstrap plugins.
> 2. For pc, drop replace ratchet's header/navigation
>      with regular web header/navigation.

In general, is it a good idea to mix ratchet and bootstrap to make a webapp?
If you want mobile and the pc version of the web, and utilize ratchet for mobile, how would you go about removing the ratchet for the pc version?

Comment: good question :) I don't have an answer but I have a question maybe you can tell how do you integrate with the android api? meaning, if you wish to access android preferences storage how would you do that? (I just came accross ratchet and wonder how do people use the phone api).  thanks...